# Creating an arraylist of multiple different objects

Tags: java, arraylist

How do i create an arraylist of many DIFFERENT OBJECTS and add their references. So like shape.add(new Rectangle(3, 2)); and like shape.add(new RightTriangle(2, 4).

Comment: Realistically these shapes should inherit from a `Shape` class/interface. Then you can use an array list of shapes, not objects.

Comment: Or of a common superclass (maybe `Shape`?)

Comment: Please don’t downvote and get my question closed..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating instance list of different objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073539/creating-instance-list-of-different-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't make an interface for these classes, you can use wildcard

```java
ArrayList<?> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
shapes.add(new WhateverYouWant());
```

Comment: So with that I can put anything I want meaning different objects like the shapes for example and it not throw an error at me

Comment: Yes but there's not much point in this approach, when you retrieve them you won't be able to call any relevant methods etc. So they might as well not be in an array in the first place.