# Raw Type with List<String> gives compilation error

Tags: java, generics, compiler-construction, intellij-idea

I have the following Generic class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericRaw<T> {
    public List<String> get() {
         return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Let us consider the case of its usage:

```
public class Usage {
    public void doSomething() {
        GenericRaw base = new GenericRaw();
        for (String x : base.get()) {   }
    }
}
```

For this code Idea doesn't give any compilation error but Java compiler itself does:

> java: incompatible types 
>   required: java.lang.String 
>   found: java.lang.Object

**Reproducible on JDK 1.6.0_33 as well as on JDK 1.7.0_17.**

Can someone help me with the explanation of this issue?

Results of my investigations.
The following variants can be successfully compiled:

> ```
> public void doSomething() {
>     GenericRaw<?> base = new GenericRaw();
>     for (String x : base.get()) {   }
> }
> ```

or even:

> ```
> public void doSomething() {
>     GenericRaw base = new GenericRaw();
>     List<String> list = base.get();
>     for (String x : list) {   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I agree that it's duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007723/combining-raw-types-and-generic-methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007723/combining-raw-types-and-generic-methods) just under different conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone help me with the explanation of this issue?

Sure. It's following the JLS's description of raw types, in [section 4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> To facilitate interfacing with non-generic legacy code, it is possible to use as a type the erasure (§4.6) of a parameterized type (§4.5) or the erasure of an array type (§10.1) whose element type is a parameterized type. Such a type is called a raw type.

The [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) of `GenericRaw<T>` is:

```
public class GenericRaw {
    public List get() { ... }
}
```

because:

> Type erasure also maps the signature (§8.4.2) of a constructor or method to a signature that has no parameterized types or type variables. The erasure of a constructor or method signature s is a signature consisting of the same name as s and the erasures of all the formal parameter types given in s.
>
> The type parameters of a constructor or method (§8.4.4), and the return type (§8.4.5) of a method, also undergo erasure if the constructor or method's signature is erased.