# Java weird compilation error with raw generic type parameter and Optionals

Tags: java, generics, option-type, raw-types

The following Java code doesn't compile (using `javac 1.8.0_121`)

```
import java.util.Optional;

class B<T> {}

public class Test {
    static B<Integer> f1(B<Object> a) { return null; }

    static B<Integer> f2() {
       Optional<B> opt = Optional.empty(); // note the raw type B
       return opt.map(Test::f1).get();
       // error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to B<Integer>
    }
}
```

My question is: Why doesn't the code compile **as above**, and why does it compile if I change `f1` to take a raw type:

```
static B<Integer> f1(B a) { return null; } // program compiles with raw B
```

My guess is that `opt.map` is inferred as returning `Optional<Object>` (instead of `Optional<B<Integer>>`) but why? I have looked at other issues with generics and type erasure (JLS 4.8), but they all deal with the situation when a method is called on a raw type itself (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771406/raw-type-with-liststring-gives-compilation-error)). Here, `opt` is not raw, it only takes a raw type parameter. Also, why does the second version (where parameter `a` is raw `B` instead of `B<Object>`) work?

**Compilation Error Message**

`Error java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to B<java.lang.Integer>`

Comment: Can you also add compilation error messages here? Ok got it my bad it was in your comments :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you call first and second version?

Comment: Adding a cast helps the compiler: `((Optional<B<Integer>>) opt.map(Test::f1)).get()` (an intermediate variable works too), see https://ideone.com/Zxl4ee

Comment: Btw doing this will work `Optional<B<Object>> opt = Optional.empty(); // note the raw type B`

Comment: @RC. I know that explicit cast works, but why should it be needed, since `f1` returns `B<Integer>` anyway.
@Samarth I know that also works, I'm just wondering why using raw `B` doesn't

Comment: Related: [Combining Raw Types and Generic Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007723/combining-raw-types-and-generic-methods).

Comment: @OleV.V. that is related, but not the same, since in that case, the method is called on the raw type, here it is called on a generic type with a raw generic type parameter (`Optional` of raw `B`). We do not call any method on raw `B`

Comment: The rule I’ve learned (and it’s probably not quite as simple as I give it here) is, when you use a raw type in a class, everything gets raw. This would agree with your observation: you call `get()` on an Òptional` that the compiler now considers raw, so you get an `Object` where you expected `B<Integer>`.

Comment: @OleV.V. But the `Optional` itself is not raw, only its type parameter `B` is raw. And also, this doesn't explain why the second version (where `f1` takes a raw `B`) compiles

Comment: I agree that it doesn’t explain why the second version can be compiled. I think it does explain why M. le Rutte’s answer helps, though.

Comment: That one works, of course, because it doesn't use raw types in the first place

Comment: `Optional<B> integerB = opt.map(Test::f1); return integerB.get();` This also seems to be working while the chained version of this is not working `return opt.map(Test::f1).get();` quite strange.

Comment: Looks like it's a legit bug in java 8, program compiles in [java 9 early access](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8177946?jql=text%20~%20%22Strange%20compilation%20error%20on%20calling%20map%20and%20get%20on%20Optional%20of%20raw%20type%20parameter%22)

Comment: I believe there could be some changes in type inference in method chaining in Java 9, not sure, though, just thought it could be another explanation for the code compiling in Java 9.

Answer (score 0):

Make the f1 use a `? extends Object`, add a wildcard type to `B`.

```
import java.util.Optional;

class B<T> {}

public class Test {
   static B<Integer> f1(B<? extends Object> a) { return null; }

   static B<Integer> f2() {
       Optional<B<?>> opt = Optional.empty(); // note the raw type B
       return opt.map(x -> f1(x)).get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited the question to specify that my question is why the **original** code doesn't compile.