# Why does a Java generic raw class erase all generics to object when type parameters are unspecified?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

If I have a class:

```
public class GenericClass<TBlah extends Number> {
    public List<String> getList() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I attempt to use that method from another class:

```
public class OtherClass {
    public void test() {
        GenericClass a = null;
        for (String s : a.getList()) {

        }
    }
}
```

Why does `a.getList()` return a `List<Object>` until I change the line above the for loop to:

```
GenericClass<Number> a = null;
```

At which point a.getList() returns a `List<String>` like it should do?

Edit: I don't understand why the contract specified by `getList()` should be affected whatsoever by how I declare my variable 'a'. `getList()` always returns a `List<String>`, it doesn't matter what **TBlah** is.

Comment: Uhm, why initialize it to `null`?

Comment: @fge Simplicity. It's irrelevant to the problem I think.

Comment: Because that's the choice made by the writers of the JLS. AFAIK, the reasoning is that if you use raw types, you don't care about generic types. The solution is to avoid using raw types.

Comment: @Motig, you're right. It is irrelebvant to the question. Same thing happens even if `a` is initialized to a non-null value.

Comment: @JBNizet is right. [And I found that a similar question was actually already answered with reference to the JLS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007723/combining-raw-types-and-generic-methods).

Comment: @JBNizet is spot on (and yair posted a link explaining the situation). What you have to keep in mind is that raw types exist **exclusively** for backwards compatibility (i.e. to allow pre-generics code to compile with generics-enabled collections classes, for example). You should *never* use them for anything else (the wildcard solves most other places where you *would* want to use them).

Comment: @EJP It could return a `List<String>`, because that `getString()` isn't affected by the 'value' of **TBlah**.

Comment: No, it can't do that, because there is no such thing as a List<String> if you're not using Generics.

Comment: @EJP this is not precise. If a class type was not declared then the code would be valid and it would return `List<String>`. The fact that a type is declared for the class but it is not used by the raw type, causes type erasure for all types in that class. I believe the most appropriate answer is JBNizet's. This is after all a design decision (maybe it has to do with compiler's implementation who knows)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because this is how generics work. Do not forget that before generics when you declared a `List` it was a list of `Object`. You were expected to put/get `Object` and you were forced to cast to get your object with the correct type. Actually it still *is* a list of `Object` in runtime.

Generics is a way for the compiler to guarentee you type safety *at compile time* assuming you have no warnings. In runtime there are no `List<String>`. There is just `List`. The compiler puts the automatic cast for you, so you are able in your code to write `String s = list.get(i)` without casting.

When you declare `GenericClass a` you are declaring a raw type (you should get a warning on this) thus the compiler does not have a way to know what type the `a.getList()` is supposed to return. So it uses `Object`. When you declare `GenericClass<Number> a = null;` now the compiler knows what type to expect for the `a.getList()` and uses the desired one.

**Edit:** It should be clarified that the compiler can know what to expect only if you respect the contract of the signature (i.e. as is the case with `GenericClass<Number>`). If you don't respect the contract (i.e. you are using a raw type that does not `extends Number`) then the contract does not apply anymore. The compiler behaves as if no type information was present. Do not forget that the compiler needs to also maintain backwards compatibility with code that was created in the pre-generics era

Comment: That's sort of sensible. But why does the compiler not know what a.getList() should return? It's right there in the method signature. And that doesn't change no matter what I declare TBlah to be... So why does it matter that I use the raw type?

Comment: Thats is not correct. It is not in the signature. The signature says a `blah that extends Number`. You have used a raw type (i.e. a simple `Object`) so the signature does not apply anymore because `Object` does not extend `Number`

Comment: But the return type of List<String> in getList() is unaffected by whatever I choose TBlah to be. So why does it matter?

Comment: @Motig very interesting question! But I don't think you will get a sensible answer as the phrasing doesn't point out explicitly that the return value of `getList()` has nothing to do with type `T`.

Comment: @TimBender Thanks, I'll update the question to make that more obvious.