# Java: Generic types inside Raw Type object or why my parametrization doesn't work

Tags: java, generics

I can't grasp why my interface parametrization doesn't work. Let's look at code below:

```
public interface IType {
  public List<String> getAllItems();
}

......
public void function(IType item) {
  for (String str : item.getAllItems()) { //DOESN'T WORK! Incompoatible types. Required String, Found: Object

  } 
}
```

Why does it return `List<Object>` instead of `List<String>`?

Comment: Generics are compile time. In run-time it does not behave as you think. Cast it to `String`.

Comment: Yes I can cast the list-reference. But actually the question is WHY?

Comment: So `List<String> foo = item.getAllItems();` doesn't work???

Comment: @stonedsquirrel it works. But `for (String str : item.getAllItems())` doesn't

Comment: Please show your implementation class and how you use it.

Comment: What do you mean it returns? Your function does not return anything, it is void. If you mean you see the type in a debugger, then as tintinmj says - there are no generics during runtime. For backward compatibility, java uses type erasure - it drops all the knowledge of generics after checking them during compilation.

Comment: That's hard to believe. What's the actual compiler error? Also check your imports and make sure it's `java.util.List` and not some other `List`.

Comment: This looks much like a understanding problem of generics, as your interface is without generics, so will its methods at runtime... gotta find back the question that answer this now.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau That's just not true. You're thinking of raw types. This won't apply to an un-parameterized interface type.

Comment: @Jirka-x1 see edit version of my question

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk Again: What's the actual compiler error?

Comment: @stonedsquirrel Incompoatible types. Required String, Found: Object

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk This definitely shouldn't happen. The error must be in some part of the code you didn't post. Did you check the imports as I mentioned?

Comment: Are you sure the `IType` interface doesn't have a type parameter?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes it has. And what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to make an assumption that your `IType` is actually a parameterized (and you've just confirmed it) type like so

```
public interface IType<E> {
    public List<String> getAllItems();
}
```

In this case, if you declare a variable (or parameter) as

```
IType item;
```

you are using a Raw Type. With a variable of a raw type, all generic types in methods or fields accessed on that variable are erased. So

```
public List<String> getAllItems();
```

becomes

```
public List getAllItems();
```

and so the `List` `Iterator` will return references of type `Object`.

```
public void function(IType item) {
    for (String str : item.getAllItems()) { // DOESN'T WORK! Incompoatible
                                            // types. Required String,
                                            // Found: Object
    }
}
```

[Combining Raw Types and Generic Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007723/combining-raw-types-and-generic-methods)