# Confusing compile error with Java generics and raw, unparameterized types

Tags: java, generics

I am experiencing a somewhat counterintuitive compiler error when using generics. What I don't understand is why using the raw type here is causing such a failure. Has anyone else experienced this?

```
public class Test {

  public static void main() {

    // works
    Alpha<Void> a1 = null;
    a1.alpha().endBeta().endAlpha();

    // compile error: cannot find symbol 'endAlpha()'
    Alpha a2 = null;
    a2.alpha().endBeta().endAlpha();
  }

  interface Alpha<T> {
    Beta<Alpha<T>> alpha();

    T endAlpha();
  }

  interface Beta<T> {
    T endBeta();
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining Raw Types and Generic Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007723/combining-raw-types-and-generic-methods)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that one but it seems to be related.

Comment: Beware the `NullPointerException` that will inevitably follow when you do get this to compile.

Comment: Of course. :) It was just a contrived example anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a reference with a raw type, *all generics are ignored* when you call a method or use a field on that object.

This is one of many reasons you should not be using raw types in new code.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying the first use of a raw type changes all further generic calls? That makes sense I guess. Man, raw types are the devil.

Comment: @Ben No, it's not the first use of a raw type. It's the fact that the reference you're calling the method through (the thing on the left side of the `.`) has a raw type.