# strange Java compilation error with typed interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have come across a very strange compilation error.  At first I thought it was a bug in IntelliJ, but now I've tried with Eclipse and see the same thing.

I have the following interface:

```
public interface PluginDriver<T extends Plugin> {
   PluginBuilder<T> getBuilder();
   Set<PluginParam> getParams();
   Set<String> getStrings();
}
```

where Plugin is an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Plugin
```

and we also have a POJO as follows:

```
public class PluginParam { ... }
```

Now I have a DriverManager to return an instance of a PluginDriver, and here I will try to use that:

```
PluginDriver driver = DriverManager.getDriver(transformer.getPlugin());
PluginBuilder builder = driver.getBuilder();
for (PluginParam o : driver.getParams()) {
    //type mismatch - cannot convert from element type Object to PluginParam
}
for (String s : driver.getStrings()) {
    //type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String
}
```

The for loop commands don't compile, for reasons that I don't understand.  The interface specifies concrete return types for those methods, not type `T`.

Now, if I change the following line:

```
PluginDriver<Plugin> driver = DriverManager.getDriver(transformer.getPlugin());
```

everything suddenly plays nicely.

Similarly, if I remove the type arguments from the interface, it will work.

I could understand that the `getBuilder()` method might not work if we hadn't correctly typed the `PluginDriver`.

But how could it possibly complain about the `getStrings()` method?

==EDIT

This is not a duplicate of [Combining Raw Types and Generic Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007723), since that question refers to a method with typed parameters.  The method I'm asking about is untyped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining Raw Types and Generic Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007723/combining-raw-types-and-generic-methods)

Answer (score 2):

The JLS says, 
"The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C."
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8

When you declared a variable of the raw interface type, you forced the member methods to have raw types also. That's what screwed up the class cast.

The documentation rules.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
PluginDriver driver = DriverManager.getDriver(transformer.getPlugin());
```

You are creating a **raw** type. Bad idea.

Can lead to all sorts of problems - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Thus the answer is simple: never do that! When you are using generic types, then make sure that you have a "generic" on (one/both) sides of your declaration/definition!

Comment: I understand that we are creating a raw type, and that's not a good idea.  But I don't understand how it can possibly affect non-typed methods like getStrings().

Comment: I think I’ve heard it said that when you use a raw type, everything gets raw. So your `getStrings()` no longer returns `Set<String>`, but raw `Set`. This would explain why `for (String s : driver.getStrings())` doesn’t compile.