# Iterate over some list returned by a generic-class method

Tags: java, generics

Something I live with for long but I didn't ever understood..

The question is the comment :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class Test {

        public static class Test1 {
            public List<String> getStrings(){
                List<String> s  = new ArrayList();
                s.add("test1");
                return s;
            }
        }

        public static class Test2<PARAM> {
            public List<String> getStrings(){
                List<String> s  = new ArrayList();
                s.add("test2");
                return s;}
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Test1 test1 = new Test1();
            Test2 test2 = new Test2();
            for (String string : test1.getStrings()) {
                System.out.println(string);
            }
            // Why do I need this cast (List<String>) ?
            for (String string : (List<String>)test2.getStrings()) {
                System.out.println(string);
            }
        }
    }
```

So why do I need the cast (List) ?

Franck

Comment: Because `Test2` is generic and you use it with a raw type

Comment: Mmm . doesn't calm my undestanding appetite ;). Found this post in the interval : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007723/combining-raw-types-and-generic-methods

Comment: That's a good interview question

Comment: Read this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it - if you want the whole story.

Comment: The link you found is correct, declaring  `Test2<Integer> test2 = new Test2<>();` works you don't need the cast anymore

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate it like this

```
Test2<String> test2 = new Test2<>();
```

I used `<String>` as a type for demonstration purposes

As mentioned before, you need to specify the type of `Test2`

Comment: maybe use `Test2<Integer> test2 = new Test2<>();` as an example to show that the type of the class is not linked to the type of the list

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify all with generic parameter types, as otherwise the compiler reverts to pre-`<>` semantics, where `List` gives only `Object` elements.

```
    public static class Test1 {
        public List<String> getStrings(){
            List<String> s  = new ArrayList<>(); // ***
            s.add("test1");
            return s;
        }
    }

    public static class Test2<PARAM> {
        public List<String> getStrings(){
            List<String> s  = new ArrayList<>(); // ***
            s.add("test2");
            return s;}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        Test2<Integer> test2 = new Test2<>(); // ***
        for (String string : test1.getStrings()) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
        // Why do I need this cast (List<String>) ?
        for (String string : test2.getStrings()) { // ***
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a quirk in the compiler with generics and type erasure. 
When a compiler compiles a generic class it does all the type checking then strips all the `<>` and creates byte code that basically looks like

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

Notice no type parameters.

the class will compile to

```
public static class Test2 {

}
```

if you have type parameters:

```
public T returnT(){
    return T;
}
```

compiles to

```
public Object returnT(){
   return Object;
}
```

It appears that if you create a generic class without a type

```
Test2 test2 = new Test2<>();
```

the compiler knows theres something wrong and asks you to explicitly cast.

```
 for (String string : (List<String>)test2.getStrings()) {
                System.out.println(string);
            }
```

If you add the type

```
Test2<Integer> test2 = new Test2<>(); // can put any type here as we're not actually using the type
```

the compiler can do some type checking and it deduces that the getStrings is of type String so it compiles

```
  for (String string : test2.getStrings()) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
```

take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) for further reading