# How to specify output type of Stream.map?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, mapping

Trying to wrap stream elements with my class `Establishment`, but it can't infer ouput type of constructor, thinking it is a stream of objects:

[image]

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getEstablishment()
  location: class java.lang.Object
```

Why and how to fix?

Can't specify type in any way

```
return q.getResultStream().<Establishment>map(Establishment::new).findFirst().orElse(new Establishment()).getEstablishment();
```

is it still possible?

Comment: Does `g.getResultStream()` return a raw `Stream` (without generic parameters)?

Comment: What does `q.getResultStream()` return, what kind of constructor does `Establishment` have (and why does a class named `Establishment` have a method named `getEstablishment()`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, there are [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) somewhere:

> To create a parameterized type of Box, you supply an actual type argument for the formal type parameter T:
>
> ```java
> Box<Integer> intBox = new Box<>();
> ```
>
> If the actual type *argument is omitted*, you create a **raw** type of Box:
>
> ```java
> Box rawBox = new Box();
> ```

It might be that in your code:

- `q.getResultStream()` returns a raw `Stream`.

  The method could look similar to:

  ```java
  public Stream getResultStream() {
      return Stream.of();
  }
  ```
- Return type of `getResultStream` is not raw, but the type of `q` is raw itself. E.g.:

  ```java
  public class Page<T> {
      public Stream<T> stream() {
          return Stream.of();
      }
  }

  public class Main {
      public static void test(Page q) {
          //                  ^^^^ raw type
          q.stream();
      }
  }
  ```

Despite the cause, the problem is: **when raw types are used [one loses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007894/6486622):**

> **the ability to use generics in any way for instance members**

So any further usage of the stream returns **raw** `Stream`. The methods of `Establishment` become *"invisible"* and compilation fails.

#### Possible fixes:

1. Explicit cast introduction:

   ```java
   Establishment establishment = ((Stream<?>) q.getResultStream())
           .map(Establishment::new)
           .findFirst()
           .orElseGet(Establishment::new);
   ```

   - The `Stream` is cast to a `Stream<?>` which is an [*unbounded wildcard type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html)
   - The `Function` in the `map` method can be viewed as a function accepting an `Object` and returning a `T` (`Establsihment`)
2. Raw types elimination

   - Raw types are used for backward compatibility
   - They are barely present in the modern source code (Generics were introduced in Java 5, which came out in 2004)
   - It is **highly** recommended to avoid them

     - See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/6486622)

---

> Can't specify type in any way
>
> ```java
>  return q.getResultStream()
>    .<Establishment>map(Establishment::new)
>    .findFirst()
>    .orElse(new Establishment())
>    .getEstablishment();
> ```
>
> is it still possible?

Please note, that Intellij IDEA might be a little bit misleading there.

Here is a minimal example that javac compiles:

```java
public class StackoverflowDemoApplication {
    private static Stream getRawStream() {
        return Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
    }

    public static void test() {
        getRawStream().<Integer>map(it -> it + "")
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
    }
}
```

but intellij shows an error:

[image: Type arguments given on a raw method in Intellij IDEA]