# Why java raw type erase types of concretized members

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, raw-types

Given below example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyTemplate<T> {

    T parameterizedObj;
    List<String> stringList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = new MyTemplate().getStringList().get(0);
    }

    public List<String> getStringList() {
        if (stringList == null) {
            stringList = new ArrayList<>();
            stringList.add("Hello");
        }
        return stringList;
    }
}
```

Below error is given when compiling

```
/home/***/test/src/main/java/MyTemplate.java:10:56
java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

When MyTemplate is used as a raw type in this form `new MyTemplate()` in line 10.

I can understand the type of `T parameterizedObj` is erased to Object.

But I can't understand why `List<String> stringList` is erased to `List`. Since it has been concretized as `List<String>`. Why?

I read the document [Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) and [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), but don't find an answer, I think they're talking about the use case of `T parameterizedObj`, not `List<String> stringList`

Comment: What do you mean by "Why"? What kind of answer are you looking for? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/11007723/5133585 for a quote in the Java Language Specification that specifies this behaviour, if that's what you want.

Comment: The `List<String>` is not “erased to `List<Object>`”, as that wouldn’t be erasure but an incompatible type change. The `List<String>` is erased to `List`.

Comment: @Sweeper, @Holger, thanks for reply. I just don't understand why the type `List<String>` of `stringList` is erased, why it's designed in this way.  I think when `MyTemplate` is used as a raw type, it just means the formal type `T` is not specified. But the type of `stringList` is definitely `List<String>`, it doesn't depend on `T`.

Comment: The declared type of `stringList`, `List<String>`, does not depend on `T` but that doesn’t matter when you access this member through the raw type `MyTemplate`. All members of the raw type will have a raw type, regardless of whether their type depends on the owner’s type parameters. A well known example is [`<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)) applied on a raw `Collection`. Its type parameter `T` does not depend on the collection’s `E`, still, calling on a raw `Collection` yields a raw `Object[]`.

Comment: Holger - All right, obviously I was in a wrong cognition, thank you for educating me.